# Can I marry a LDS/Mormon woman? I know the Qur'an allows marriage to believers, but are Mormons believers?

Tags: nikah, women, non-muslim, other-religions

I know that many questions have been asked about marrying spouses that are "believers," but who are not Muslims, and that the Qur'an does make it permissible as long as they are devout believers, etc. **However, I was wondering if a Mormon/LDS woman is considered a "believer."**

Mormons do consider themselves Christians, and they are some of the most devout religious people I know. They don't drink alcohol (or even coffee or tea because of the addictive qualities of caffeine), don't have pre-marital sex (they actually follow it), they fast every month, they pay tithes/alms, pray frequently, make covenants with God, dress modestly, place a HUGE emphasis on the family, don't curse, don't watch R-rated movies, read from the scriptures morning and night, constantly serve their communities, etc. She is full of light, hope, faith, purity, integrity, happiness, etc. I found that Mormons had many similarities with Islam, actually.

But I wasn't sure if they are considered "believers" by our standards because they don't accept the traditional Christian "Trinity" since they believe God and Christ are separate individuals... so I wasn't sure if that makes them idolaters.

I love this woman a lot and she loves me a lot as well. We are both very respectful of each other's religions, and know that we support each other in staying true to our respective faiths. Also, I know that she will help me raise up a righteous family with wholesome and Godly values.

Comment: related: http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/73/22

Comment: @goldPseudo, thank you so much! I didn't know this was such a hotly contested debate! Thanks for directing me to your question. From being around my girlfriend, she knows the the Bible better than any other Christian I know. She teaches Old and New Testament for a living at a university, actually. The Book of Mormon does not replace the Bible she repeatedly tells me. She is a strong believer in the Bible. But it seems like this Mormons' status as "People of the Book" is still debated, according to the link you provided. And Mormons don't consider themselves polytheists... Lots to think about

Answer (score 3):

According to Islam, male muslims are only allowed to marry people of the book, which is Jews and Christians. In light of this, as shown here:

Mormons are a group that broke from Christianity. This sect was founded by Joseph Smith, who was born in the early 19th century. He claimed to be a Prophet and to adhere to the Jewish books as well as the Book of Mormon, which is claimed to be a completion of the Torah of the pamphlets that were sent to Musa  sallallaahu  `alayhi  wa  sallam ( may  Allaah exalt his mention ). Joseph and his followers encountered much oppression from the Christians. Finally, the Christians caught him and his brother and killed them, refusing to accept that they (he and his brother) were still Christians. So Mormons are not considered from the people of the Books.

(Source: https://fatwa.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=87946)

So in that case, it seems to be a no.

Answer (score 0):

I was once in that place as well. You have to think in long term, beauty don't last forever but characters do. Mormons get involve in your personal life (I mean not in your view). I do not who told you that Mormons do not have pre marital sex, they actually do have sex. If you live outside US, than you would not know in US a lot of people do not have health insurance and there is poverty in some parts. Some people chose to go to mission if they are paid for a surgery or any other issue. You will have to pay tithing and keep getting influence. Lets suppose everything I told you for moment is not true, If a girl is so religious that she follows her religion to the letter than what would your children be ??? They are influential and you are Muslim outside Muslim majority country or your own country. Think fast and slow. Take a step back. If you really love the woman go ahead but if you are thinking about other issues than I would suggest do not do it. They have Book of Mormon with KJ Bible and there is contradiction between these, But I would consider them people of Book but not of Christian faith. They believe God was born on another planet, came to this earth and got married. They believe in baptism of dead. Take a holistic approach and decide, but there is one thing if you are strong in your faith and love your woman, she will change for you (this is most important), Islam teaches love & respect for Mother. You might try it after you have kids, be gentle and love her, I hope you have her and get what you want.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE.  This site's interested in what Islam says about the matter; we're not here to give marriage advice.

Answer (score 0):

As a member of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints, I think you should have some insight as to how your beloved might feel about this. We believe that in being sealed in our temples so that we can be with our families forever. It can be a little sad sometimes to have that belief conflict with the marriage you're in. To love someone so much and then never see them in the afterlife? It can be a sad, and potentially lonely thought.
As for your question, I consider Mormonism to be a branch of Christianity. A Christian is just someone who harbors a belief in Christ. If the Qur'an says you can marry a Christian believer, you could probably marry a member of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints.

Answer (score 0):

The Qur'an prohibits men from marrying women that are polytheists and idol worshippers until they believe. Allah (azza wa jal) even says that it is far better to marry a slave believer than a beautiful mushrik. Mormons believe that every universe has a "god", so they are polytheists. Because of this, they are not marriageable for us as Muslims.