# If a non-Muslim is a great person, He fulfills everyone rights so still will he go to hell after dying as he is a non-Muslim?

Tags: non-muslim

If a non-Muslim is a great person, he fulfills everyone rights and do a lot of good deeds than Muslims and never break anyone heart so still will he go to hell after dying as he is a non-Muslim. what are Islam teaching and rules over it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that by definition, a non-Muslim can not be a great person who fulfills everyone's rights, because he has already contravened the right of Allah by doing *kufr* and *shirk*.

> ومن أظلم ممن افترى على الله كذبا أو كذب بآياته إنه لا يفلح الظالمون
>
> And who is more unjust than one who invents about Allah a lie or denies His verses? Indeed, the wrongdoers will not succeed.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 6:21](http://quran.com/6/21)</sup>

> إن الشرك لظلم عظيم
>
> Indeed, association [with him] is great injustice.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 31:13](http://quran.com/31/13)</sup>

In Islam we do not speak about the fate of any particular individual, but we say in general that everyone who dies as a non-Muslim will be in hell, regardless of their deeds, and any reward for their deeds will have been granted to them during their lifetimes.

> ومن يبتغ غير الإسلام دينا فلن يقبل منه وهو في الآخرة من الخاسرين
>
> And whoever desires other than Islam as religion - never will it be accepted from him, and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 3:85](http://quran.com/3/85)</sup>

> ومن يكفر بالإيمان فقد حبط عمله وهو في الآخرة من الخاسرين
>
> And whoever denies the faith - his work has become worthless, and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:5](http://quran.com/5/5)</sup>

> والذين كفروا فتعسا لهم وأضل أعمالهم
>
> But those who disbelieve - for them is misery, and He will waste their deeds.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 47:8](http://quran.com/47/8)</sup>

> والذين كفروا وكذبوا بآياتنا أولئك أصحاب النار خالدين فيها وبئس المصير
>
> But the ones who disbelieved and denied Our verses - those are the companions of the Fire, abiding eternally therein; and wretched is the destination.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 64:10](http://quran.com/64/10)</sup>