# What is the award for non-Muslim on their best deeds?

Tags: practical-islam, non-muslim, deeds

As we are Muslim Allah anounced award   for our each good deeds like jannah for good people but if the non-Muslim is same and doing good deeds like he is helping others he is not telling alie he is good with his family then what is his reward even if he did not believe on Allah and not accept Islam ?

Comment: They will be rewarded inshallah for their good deeds in this life. Unfortunately, not many Muslims at our time practically present a true image of Islam and not many Muslim countries show any advantages in following Islam. Non-believers in our time therefore are not comparable with those in Arabia at the time of the Prophet (pbuh) who rejected his message despite knowing its truth.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If a non-Muslim is a great person, He fulfills everyone rights so still will he go to hell after dying as he is a non-Muslim?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/50885/if-a-non-muslim-is-a-great-person-he-fulfills-everyone-rights-so-still-will-he)

Comment: Em not asking about hell em asking about reward

Answer (score 1):

There are different opinions which also depends on different circumstances. One is:

> Indeed, those who believed and those who were Jews or Christians or Sabeans—those who believed in Allah and the Last Day and did righteousness—will have their reward with their Lord, and no fear will there be concerning them, nor will they grieve.
> <sub>Quran 2:62</sub>

This appears to suggest that they will be rewarded for their deeds as long as they believed in God, day of judgement and did good deeds. If they wouldn't grieve and have no fear, this implies they will enter the Jannah (But Imam Ghazali disagrees and suggests that just because they're among those who will grieve doesn't mean they will be among the successful - They will not enter hell but neither will they enter heaven). However your question is about those who do not believe in Allah so it doesn't really apply to them.

There are scholars who maintain that this Ayat applies only till the arrival of Prophet Muhammad (PBUH). After the arrival of Prophet Muhammad, Islam is considered the only way for salvation. That reasoning is usually based on the following:

> And whoever desires other than Islam as religion—never will it be accepted from him, and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers
> <sub>Quran 3:85</sub>

Also

> “Verily, whosoever sets up partners (in worship) with Allâh, then
>   Allâh has forbidden Paradise to him, and the Fire will be his
>   abode”
> <sub>Quran 5:72</sub>

and

> “And We shall turn to whatever deeds they (disbelievers, polytheists,
>   sinners) did, and We shall make such deeds as scattered floating
>   particles of dust” 
> <sub>Quran 25:23</sub>

and thanks to [uMh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/20218/umh):

> Indeed, those who disbelieve in Allah and His messengers and wish to
>   discriminate between Allah and His messengers and say, "We believe in
>   some and disbelieve in others," and wish to adopt a way in between.
>   Those are the disbelievers, truly. And We have prepared for the
>   disbelievers a humiliating punishment.
> <sub>Quran 4:150-151</sub>

Also a Hadith:

> ‘Aa’ishah (may Allaah be pleased with her) asked the Prophet (peace
>   and blessings of Allaah be upon him) a question similar to that asked
>   here. She (may Allaah be pleased with her) said: “O Messenger of
>   Allaah, during the Jaahiliyyah Ibn Jud’aan used to uphold the ties of
>   kinship and feed the poor. Will that be of any avail to him?” He said,
>   “No, that will not be of any avail to him, because he never said ‘O
>   Lord, forgive me my sins on the Day of Judgement.’”
> <sub>Sahih Muslim 214</sub>

and again, thanks to [UMH](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/20218/umh):

> By Him in Whose hand is the life of Muhammad, he who amongst the
>   community of Jews or Christians hears about me, but does not affirm
>   his belief in that with which I have been sent and dies in this state
>   (of disbelief), he shall be but one of the denizens of Hell-Fire.
> <sub>Sahih Muslim 70</sub>

So overwhelming evidence suggests that if a person was alive at the time or after the arrival of Prophet Muhammad and did not believe in him, that person would be among the people who get punished, not rewarded.

Comment: The question says "did not believe on Allah" ... even though I'd disagree with you giving this interpretation of 2:62 the status of a valid opinion in light of [4:150-151](https://legacy.quran.com/4/150-151) and [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/muslim/1/293) etc.

Comment: @UmH Fair point, I will edit it out