# What is the fate of non-Muslims in Akhirah?

Tags: hadith, non-muslim

What will happen to people in Akhirah who die as non-Muslims?

About 70-75 percent of all people are non-Muslims and follow other religions. What is their fate in Akhirah?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do non-Muslims have chance to go to Paradise?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1361/do-non-muslims-have-chance-to-go-to-paradise)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

See https://islamqa.info/en/1244 for details.

Short answer: the rejecters will be in the hellfire abiding there in forever.

> So the outcome for both of them is that they will be in the Fire, abiding eternally therein. And that is the recompense of the wrong-doers [[Surah al-Hashr 59:17]](https://muflihun.com/59#17)

Comment: So 80 percent of people who die as non-muslim will burn in fire of hell??

Comment: I am not sure if it's 80% but if it is my answer is: Allah (SWT) has said He will forgive any sin He wants except shirk and with no doubts Allah's promise is true. "Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives what is less than that for whom He wills. And he who associates others with Allah has certainly fabricated a tremendous sin." - Qur'an 4:48

Comment: Please mark it as answer if you are satisfied :) Jazakummulahu khairan

Comment: @mkhan3189: "Disbeliever" are people who are convinced that Islam is the right religion and do not adopt it only due to their vested interest. I don't think most of non-muslim fall in that category

Comment: "Had we but listened or used our intelligence, we would not have been among the dwellers of the Blazing Fire." [Al-Qur'an 67:10]

But I partially agree just because some scholars have made mentioned of people who have not ever been given dawah' and have died in that condition (e.g, non muslim mentally disabled), and according to scholars they will be tested (on day of judgement) by showing them hell and heaven and will be ordered to be jump into hell if they follow they will be successful and if they disobey they will be amongst people of hell. Again this is just opinion.

Allah knows best

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote such answers when it's clear answer and they don't even comment! - o well, it's just stackexchange

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin my brother, this is from the tafseer and I only quoted that, didn't take it out of context. Can you explain what's the right context? Fear Allah!

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin I understand where you coming from, i have updated my answer accordingly. JazaakAllahu khayran akhi. wassalaam.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of non-Muslims according to Islam:

1. Those who received the massage of Islam and rejected it.
2. Those who didn't receive the massage of Islam.

Non-Muslims of the first group will go to hell. Prophet (peace be upon him) said regarding them:

> "By the One in Whose hand is the soul of Muhammad, there is no-one of
>   this ummah, Jew or Christian, **who hears of me then dies without
>   believing in that with which I have been sent, but he will be one of
>   the people of Hell.**" (Reported by Muslim, may Allaah have mercy on
>   him, in al-Saheeh, 153).

People of the second group (those who died without receiving the massage of Islam) will be tested again in the hereafter. They won't be punished with hell because Allah almighty says in the Qur'an (interpretation of the meaning):

> Whoever is guided is only guided for [the benefit of] his soul. And
>   whoever errs only errs against it. And no bearer of burdens will bear
>   the burden of another. **And never would We punish until We sent a
>   messenger.** [Qur'an 17:15]

If they pass the test in the hereafter, they will enter Paradise.

Comment: What is considered receiving the message?