# Can my parents enter paradise

Tags: non-muslim, jannah, parents

My mom and dad are deceased, now, i wonder if my mom and dad will enter paradise, they grew up in a catholic religions, they have never know or hear about Muslim religion, but both of my parents are kind and very religious people.
 Will they be excused by Allah?

Comment: A related Question http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1361/do-non-muslims-have-chance-to-go-to-paradise?rq=1

Comment: You can still pray for your parents like Prophet Moses and Prophet Abraham did.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for your loss.

Nobody can tell you what Allah does or will do. All you one can answer is, according to Islam, can someone who never heard of Islam go to heaven.

This would make your question similar [to this one](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/368/what-is-the-fate-of-someone-who-died-never-having-heard-of-islam).

Similar things can be seen in the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fate_of_the_unlearned#Islam). I am always reluctant to site Wikipedia but this one gives faire references.

And more logically, if God is all merciful, I have trouble imagining Him punishing someone for not hearing about his message.  Having a good opinion of Allah (حسن الظن بالله) is one of the [most important deeds](http://en.islamtoday.net/artshow-426-3251.htm). Do good and live in peace.

Comment: Perhaps you could've quoted the most relevant pieces here.

Comment: I always prefer it if people read for themselves, the effort for the truth should be shared. But perhaps you're right. Though I cannot decide, which one do you consider the most relevant ?

Comment: What ever you feel right. But, I'm sorry I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of the question you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Those who never heard about Islam are excused, but they will be tested in the day of resurrection

http://www.alquranenglish.com/al-isra/quran-english-al-isra-15