# A friend asked me about "the hate speech of Islam"; how should I reply?

Tags: dawah

He actually sent me a message with this content:

> The Islam is clearly hate speech, have a look at these parts:
>
> Believers are loved by God, whereas infidels are hated to the extent
>   that they are tortured for eternity (3:32, 4:56) merely for not
>   believing.  Muslims are told not to take unbelievers as friends (3:28)
>   and to shun them (3:118).  Those outside the circle are called
>   “helpers of evil” (25:55), “wicked” (4:160), “fond of lies” (5:42) and
>   compared to the worst of animals (8:55, 7:176, 7:179).  Muslims are
>   told to be merciful to each other, but ruthless to those outside of
>   the faith (48:29).  Violence is also sanctioned against those who are
>   obstinate against Islamic rule (8:12-13, 9:5).

How should I answer him? He is Hindu.

Comment: Maybe relevant http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28682/how-do-non-violent-muslims-explain-the-violent-verses-of-the-koran

Comment: These are a lot of Verses have you checked them and their context? I mean 3:32 is not about torture. And some of these Verses speak about the hereafter, so why does he care if he isn't a Muslim. And the word "*awlya'* اولياء" and friends are not synonyms at all! So any of these Verses can be discussed and explained by context and by the agreed or concluded meaning of Muslim scholars. But yes as Muslims we believe that non-Believers will be tortured in hell etc.

Comment: Not all believe that a non Muslim will be sent to hell but rather the kafir will. Because many scholars argue that not all non Muslims are kafir.

Comment: @Medi1Saif yes I read them. You mention 3:32, well have you read 3:32? it is not about torture no. But it states `Allah does not like the disbelievers.` well that's like saying disbelievers are lower humans, you are more than welcome to dislike them. You are actually openly _encouraged_ to dislike disbelievers, because that's what allah does. Now please, discuss and explain 3:32 in depth and with context, feel free to leave a lengthy answer, I really want to discuss. Furthermore: "why care about the afterlife" well if you get damned to bricks in afterlife, that means you are a lesser human.

Comment: @Medi1Saif i really wish your arguments were stronger. You first point is very weak sadly, unimportant. Then you say something about the arabic translation of the word friends, but what about the rest? it's like you toss a drop of water in a huge burning fire and tap yourself on the shoulder "i saved the day". Simply saying "any of these Verses can be discussed and explained" is not an answer. At best, you invalidated 3:28 but even if you replace friends with "supporters, allies, helpers" it's still hate speech. I mean it's sad, I post this in an islam expert forum. And that is all you got?

Comment: @Toskan I'm not giving an answer just a comment. Maybe you should split your question in parts so that we can answer them as is its hard to give a readable and focused answer!

Comment: @Toskan my point isn't weak or unimportant: If somebody quotes Verses without context then he could pretend a lot. While if you know the context this make things clearer. And at least you will find a similar hate speech in the bible as it refers to the same God. So either we can discuss it Verse by Verse or by topic. But as is it would be hard to give a readable answer, as apparently a rather brief answer wouldn't be sufficient. And I'd advice you to read and try to understand your religion first before questioning it based on foreign teachings!

Comment: @Medi1Saif Your comment was weak and unimportant, because the only details you reveal, are weak and unimportant. If you say "well non-believers will get tortured in hell for eternity, why does he care?" well because it's clearly hate speech. If I would say all women will get tortured to eternity for the gender in the thereafter would you call me a sexist? 
Your explanation is "it is so hard to understand that it's not hatespeech, it's almost impossible to explain". Well it slowly starts to grow on me why it is so difficult to defend against it.

Comment: @Medi1Saif just pick two verses and put them into context for example. It's a start. What about 8:55, 7:176, 7:179?

you last comment: you drag in the bible, for whatever weak reasons. It's like saying "that guy over there stabbed a person and he doesn't get blamed so hard, well so I guess I can stab another person 10 times and shouldn't be blamed neither". 
Now the world is not 0 and 1. There is a grey zone in between. Now the new testament is a lot about cheek turning. Something I cannot find in the quran.

Comment: @Medi1Saif the thing is, there is a big part of the people who understand that things happened thousand years ago, and were applicable during those times. Stoning someone for being gay seems not like a good solution nowadays, does it? The problem is not this big part. The problem is the small part that reads the quran like a physics book. Those people exist in christianity as well. With the only but big difference, that there seems to be ways less hate speech in the bible than in the quran.

Comment: So in the next 100 years if times change and doing something awful is made the norm then religion should be changed again. Doesn't sounds like a religion to me.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should answer that there is no hate speech in Islam. To pick out some ayat from the Holy Qur'an without any context as a proof that Islam is violent and hateful is not giving a truthful picture of the final monotheistic religion.

You can find in the Bible even worse passages of hate and then conclude that Christianity is a violent religion. Nobody would do that.

Have a look at this clip,where some students in the Netherlands made a little experiment in the streets.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEnWw_lH4tQ

Secondly, God's **mercy** is the most frequently mentioned quality of God in the Qur'an. His mercy is all-embracing and all-inclusive. He is merciful towards all his creation, He even was merciful to Shaitan when He allowed him to survive. His mercy is infinite and includes people who do not know Him or fight against Him.

How many disbelievers live a very comfortable life? It is because of Allah's mercy. So how can this merciful creator propagate hate?

> ***Al-Rahman*** (الرحمان): Literally meaning the All-compassionate or the All-merciful. This is the second most famous name of God in Islam. In
>   the Qur’an God tells the Prophet Mohammad:
>
> “Say, ‘Invoke ‘‘Allah’’ or invoke ‘‘al-Rahman.’’ Whichever [of His
>   Names] you may invoke, to Him belong the Best Names.’” (17:110)
>
> This term is mentioned **169** times in the Qur’an. Al-Rahim
>
> ***Al-Rahim*** (الرحيم): Literally meaning the Compassionate or the
>   Merciful. It is the most repeated attribute of God in the Qur’an. It
>   is mentioned **226** times in the Qur’an. According to some hadiths,
>   Al-Rahman refers to the compassion and mercy of God for all creatures
>   and al-Rahim refers to the special extra compassion and mercy that He
>   has for the believers. Thus, it may be more accurate to translate
>   al-Rahman into the All-merciful and al-Rahim into the Most merciful.

(http://www.al-islam.org/image-god-quran)

Comment: "He even was merciful to Shaitan when He allowed him to survive" allowed him to survive in order to torture him forever. Doesn't sound like mercy to me, sounds like extreme cruelty.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the obvious thing to do is read those Qur'an verses one by one.  Experience shows that verses, translations, and snippets are carefully cherry-picked, and they're usually straightforward to debunk by actually reading the Qur'an.

Throughout this list, we see the repeated theme of taking Qur'an verses that relate to battle and war, and presenting them as if they're everyday guidelines.  The Qur'an translation by Maulana Wahiduddin Khan addresses this problem directly under "Jihad is a Peaceful Ideological Struggle" (starting on page xvii):

> Such verses, relate, in a restricted sense, to those who have unilaterally attacked the Muslims.  ...
>
> Similarly, Jesus Christ said, `Do not think that I came to bring peace on Earth.  I did not come to bring peace, but a sword.' ([Matthew, 10:34](http://biblehub.com/matthew/10-34.htm))

---

- "tortured for eternity merely for not believing":

  > Say, "Obey Allah and the Messenger." But if they turn away - then indeed, Allah does not like the disbelievers.  -- [Qur'an 3:30](https://quran.com/3:30)
  >
  > Indeed, those who disbelieve in Our verses - We will drive them into a Fire. Every time their skins are roasted through We will replace them with other skins so they may taste the punishment. Indeed, Allah is ever Exalted in Might and Wise. -- [Qur'an 4:56](https://quran.com/4:56)

  In Islam, indeed, we accept there is punishment for those who reject the message of Muhammad (along with sinning).  Whether or not the punishment is eternal, it's complicated (see e.g. [Do non-Muslims have a chance to go to Paradise?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1361/17163), and [Do people who never convert to islam still go to hell even if they believe in God?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35427/17163)), and up to Allah's all-knowing, perfect judgement.  However, judging from [many ahadith](http://orbitislam.com/ways-to-enter-jannah/), it only takes a modicum of goodness to get into Paradise.  It also seems that time behaves differently after death ([Qur'an 22:47](https://quran.com/22:47): "...a day with your Lord is like a thousand years of those which you count.").
- "Muslims are told not to take unbelievers as friends":

  > Let not believers take disbelievers as allies rather than believers. And whoever [of you] does that has nothing with Allah , except when taking precaution against them in prudence. And Allah warns you of Himself, and to Allah is the [final] destination. -- [Qur'an 3:28](https://quran.com/3:28)

  Many Muslims have non-Muslim friends (including your Hindu friend, it seems), and that ayah does not say otherwise.  In fact, the Qur'an itself says the complete opposite:

  > Allah does not forbid you from those who do not fight you because of religion and do not expel you from your homes - from being righteous toward them and acting justly toward them. Indeed, Allah loves those who act justly. -- Qur'an [60:8](https://quran.com/60:8)
- "Muslims are told... to shun [unbelievers]":

  > O you who have believed, do not take as intimates those other than yourselves, for they will not spare you [any] ruin. They wish you would have hardship. Hatred has already appeared from their mouths, and what their breasts conceal is greater. We have certainly made clear to you the signs, if you will use reason. -- [Qur'an 3:118](https://quran.com/3:118)

  Again, the cited ayah does not support the claim, and the Qur'an says the complete opposite:

  > And when you are greeted with a greeting, greet [in return] with one better than it or [at least] return it [in a like manner]. Indeed, Allah is ever, over all things, an Accountant.  -- [Qur'an 4:86](https://quran.com/4:86)
- "Those outside the circle are called 'helpers of evil'":

  > But they worship rather than Allah that which does not benefit them or harm them, and the disbeliever is ever, against his Lord, an assistant [to Satan]. -- [Qur'an 25:55](https://quran.com/25:55)

  There's inconsistent translations of this (see [Islam Awakened](http://islamawakened.com/quran/25/55/)).  E.g. the version "...the unbelievers are defiant against their Lord" is almost a tautology.  I don't think it's intended to mean that disbelievers are going around invoking Satan.  The next ayah suggests it's more of an expression of concern:

  > And We have not sent you, [O Muhammad], except as a bringer of good tidings and a warner. -- [Qur'an 25:56](https://quran.com/25:56)
- "Those outside the circle are called 'wicked'...":

  > For wrongdoing on the part of the Jews, We made unlawful for them [certain] good foods which had been lawful to them, and for their averting from the way of Allah many [people], -- [Qur'an 4:160](https://quran.com/4:160)

  Seems unrelated to the claim.
- "Those outside the circle are called 'fond of lies'...":

  > [They are] avid listeners to falsehood, devourers of [what is] unlawful. So if they come to you, [O Muhammad], judge between them or turn away from them. And if you turn away from them - never will they harm you at all. And if you judge, judge between them with justice. Indeed, Allah loves those who act justly. -- [Qur'an 5:42](https://quran.com/5:42)

  The preceding ayah gives the context:

  > O Messenger, let them not grieve you who hasten into disbelief of those who say, "We believe" with their mouths, but their hearts believe not, and from among the Jews. [They are] avid listeners to falsehood, listening to another people who have not come to you. They distort words beyond their [proper] usages, saying "If you are given this, take it; but if you are not given it, then beware." But he for whom Allah intends fitnah - never will you possess [power to do] for him a thing against Allah . Those are the ones for whom Allah does not intend to purify their hearts. For them in this world is disgrace, and for them in the Hereafter is a great punishment.  -- [Qur'an 5:41](https://quran.com/5:41)

  So it's referring to people who say "we believe" but don't; not those "outside the circle".

  (I asked about the Jewish reference here: [Does Qur'an 5:41 mean that all Jews "listen eagerly to lies", or that among the Jews there are some who "listen eagerly to lies"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35735/17163))
- "Those outside the circle are... compared to the worst of animals":

  > Indeed, the worst of living creatures in the sight of Allah are those who have disbelieved, and they will not [ever] believe -- [Qur'an 8:55](https://quran.com/8:55)

  Wait, the sentence hasn't finished.

  > Indeed, the worst of living creatures in the sight of Allah are those who have disbelieved, and they will not [ever] believe - The ones with whom you made a treaty but then they break their pledge every time, and they do not fear Allah. -- [Qur'an 8:55-58](https://quran.com/8:55)

  So, those who break treaties are referred to as "the worst of living creatures", which is consistent with the history of the ayah:

  > This refers especially to the Jews. After arriving in Madina, the Prophet (peace be on him) concluded a treaty of mutual co-operation and good neighbourliness with them. ... But somehow the Jewish rabbis and scholars were irked... They were constantly engaged, therefore, in efforts to sabotage the new religious movement. -- [IslamicStudies.info](http://www.islamicstudies.info/tafheem.php?sura=8&verse=56)
- "Those outside the circle are... compared to the worst of animals" (again):

  > And if We had willed, we could have elevated him thereby, but he adhered [instead] to the earth and followed his own desire. So his example is like that of the dog: if you chase him, he pants, or if you leave him, he [still] pants. That is the example of the people who denied Our signs. So relate the stories that perhaps they will give thought. -- [Qur'an 7:176](https://quran.com/7:176)

  This is described as "...the tale of the man..." in several translations (see [IslamAwakened](http://islamawakened.com/quran/7/175/)).  The preceding ayah:

  > And recite to them, [O Muhammad], the news of him to whom we gave [knowledge of] Our signs, but he detached himself from them; so Satan pursued him, and he became of the deviators. -- [Qur'an 7:175](https://quran.com/7:175)

  It's a bit of a stretch to say it's comparing disbelievers to dogs.
- "Those outside the circle are... compared to the worst of animals" (again):

  > And We have certainly created for Hell many of the jinn and mankind. They have hearts with which they do not understand, they have eyes with which they do not see, and they have ears with which they do not hear. Those are like livestock; rather, they are more astray. It is they who are the heedless. -- [Qur'an 7:179](https://quran.com/7:179)

  This is not about those "outside the circle" it's about "many of the jinn and mankind".
- "Muslims are told to be merciful to each other, but ruthless to those outside of the faith":

  > Muhammad is the Messenger of Allah; and those with him are forceful against the disbelievers, merciful among themselves. You see them bowing and prostrating [in prayer], seeking bounty from Allah and [His] pleasure. Their mark is on their faces from the trace of prostration. That is their description in the Torah. And their description in the Gospel is as a plant which produces its offshoots and strengthens them so they grow firm and stand upon their stalks, delighting the sowers - so that Allah may enrage by them the disbelievers. Allah has promised those who believe and do righteous deeds among them forgiveness and a great reward. -- [Qur'an 48:29](https://quran.com/48:29)

  This is in [Surah 48](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Fath) "The Victory".  This is in the context of battle, where Muslims were being [persecuted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persecution_of_Muslims_by_Meccans).
- "Violence is also sanctioned against those who are obstinate against Islamic rule":

  > [Remember] when your Lord inspired to the angels, "I am with you, so strengthen those who have believed. I will cast terror into the hearts of those who disbelieved, so strike [them] upon the necks and strike from them every fingertip."  That is because they opposed Allah and His Messenger. And whoever opposes Allah and His Messenger - indeed, Allah is severe in penalty. -- [Qur'an 8:12-13](https://quran.com/8:12)

  This is in [Surah 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Anfal) "The Spoils of War", in the context of the [Battle of Badr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Badr).  Soldiers kill people---it's not limited to Muslim soldiers.

  > And when the sacred months have passed, then kill the polytheists wherever you find them and capture them and besiege them and sit in wait for them at every place of ambush. But if they should repent, establish prayer, and give zakah, let them [go] on their way. Indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful. -- [Qur'an 9:5](https://quran.com/9:5)

  This is the so-called [Sword Verse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_Verse); Wikipedia writes:

  > According to mainstream Islamic scholarship, the verse relates to a specific event in Islamic history. [Namely] that Arabian Pagans made and broke a covenant with Arabic Muslims. The verses immediately preceding and following 9:5, [9:4](https://quran.com/9:4) and [9:6](http://quran.com/9:6), make the context very clear: Only those Pagans who broke the covenant were subject to violent repercussions. Furthermore, any Pagans who honored the covenant as well as those who repented were to be spared.

Comment: acting justly is not taking soemone as a friend. That is a very weak verse if that is all you got. Basically "don't screw them over just because they are non-muslim". 3:118 the cited verse does backup the claim. I wonder why you say so.
if you are forced to believe (which is horrible) and then you say "we believe" but don't, then you are really screwed which is even worse, isn't it?

Comment: _I wonder why you say so. if you are forced to believe (which is horrible)...._ The Qu'ran clearly says there is no compulsion in religion. Quit your virtue signalling! _...and then you say "we believe" but don't, then you are really screwed which is even worse, isn't it?_ It is meant for people who want to mock a believer and make him return back to his religion.