# Who are the Sabians?

Tags: ahlul-kitab, other-religions

I've seen several groups "identified" with them from the Mandeans to the Hermeticist but as mentioned above I'm distrustful of Wikipedia and the Internet at large.

Comment: Please note that your question has been asked before [Who are the sabeans?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2266/who-are-sabeans?rq=1) if you don't see it covered adequately there edit your question and point at what you are missing.

Comment: Yes, thank you, is strange that when writting the question this didn't came up among the suggestions nor in the search tab.

Answer (score -2):

I quote here from Abdulla Yusuf Ali commentary for the verse 62 in Sura 2 of Holy Quran, this is where one occurrence of sabians is in the Quran

> Latest researches have revealed a small remnant of a religious
> community numbering about 2,000 souls in Lower Iraq, near Basra . In
> Arabic they are called Subbi (plural Subba). They are also called
> Sabians and Nasoraeans, or Mandaeans, or Christians of St. John. They
> claim to be Gnostics, or Knowers of the Great Life. They dress in
> white, and believe in frequent immersions in water. Their Book Ginza
> is in a dialect of Aramaic. They have theories of Darkness and Light
> as in Zoroastrianism, They use the name Yardan (Jordan) for any river.
> They live in peace and harmony among their Muslim neighbours. They
> resemble the Sabi'un mentioned in the Qur'an, but are not probably
> identical with them. The pseudo-Sabians of Harran , who attracted the
> attention of Khalifah Ma'munal Rashid in 830 A.C. by their long hair
> and peculiar dress probably adopted the name as it was mentioned in
> the Qur'an, in order to claim the privileges of the People of the
> Book. They were Syrian Star-worshippers with Hellenistic tendencies,
> like the Jews contemporary with Jesus. There was another people called
> the Sabaens, who played an important part in the history of early
> early Arabia , and are known through their inscriptions in an alphabet
> allied to the Phoenician and Babylonian. They had a flourishing
> kingdom in the Yemen tract in South Arabia about 800-700 B.C., though
> their origin may have been in North Arabia . They worshipped the
> planets and stars (Moon, Sun, Venus). Probably the Queen of Sheba is
> connected with them. They succumbed to Abyssinia about 350 AC. and to
> Persia about 579 A.C. Their capital was near San'a . They had
> beautiful stone buildings, in which the pointed arch is noticeable.

Comment: Thanks that was clarifying