# What is the Injil that is referred to in Qur'an?

Tags: tafseer, bible

I have been doing some research to find similarity between the three Holy books (Torah, Injil and the Holy Qur'an), and one of the things that I came across is that the Injil was written by the followers of Jesus, whereas Christians claim that it was not a book sent down by God, rather it was a book of the description of Jesus's life.

If so, what exactly is the Qur'an referring to when it uses the term "Injil"?

Comment: The base question is very good, something which I often wonder yet can not fully answer myself. However, I don't understand what you mean when you say " and one of the things that I came across is that the Injil was written by the followers of Jesus, whereas Christians claim that it was not a book sent down by God, rather it was a book of the description of Jesus's life." Could you clear that up for us? Then I think I might be able to attempt an answer tailored to your question.

Comment: In the Turkish community, incil stands for the bible.

Comment: @Siyah Interesting, but off topic. That doesn't answer his question. 'The' Biblical canon(s) is(are) definately not the 'Injil' which the Quran refers to.

Comment: @A.Concerned.Lurker , could the injil be the bible or a different holy book, as Christians say that the bible was written many years after the death of jesus,

Comment: but reading a verse from the quran "ALLAH is HE besides Whom there is none worthy of worship, the Living, the Self-Subsisting and All-Sustaining. HE has sent down to thee the Book containing the truth and fulfilling that which precedes it; and HE has sent down the Torah and the Gospel  before this, as a guidance to the people; and HE has sent down the Discrimination ."—Qur'an, Surah 3:3-4, what are the holy books i am familiar with the torah and quran but i am not familiar with the zabour and injil

Comment: so what are these books and through whom where they sent down, was the injil written in the time of jesus or befor or after

Comment: @Aboudi I love your questions. What I can say is that as per the Quran, the Injil was a revealed scripture given to Isa (Jesus), just as we believe the Torah was given to Musa (Moses) and the Quran to Muhammad. Emphasis on revealed scripture. Orthodox and other traditional streams of Judaism also believe that the Torah was revealed to Moses by God, although secular scholars dispute this. Traditional Muslims would agree with the traditional Jewish viewpoint, although we additionally believe that the Torah has been corrupted over time...

Comment: ...The identity of the Injil is much more difficult to answer. Part of the problem lies in the fact that some Quran translations have errenously translated Zabur as 'psalms' and Injil as 'Gospel', leading to an incorrect albeit widespread view that the Injil refers to sections of the modern Bible. From my research, I can safely say that the best conclusion is that the identity of the Injil and Zabur is lost. The Christian Bible is not a single book, it is a collection of dozens of books (the number of which is contested by the various Christian denominations), and it is not a...

Comment: ...revealed scripture. I know this is quite a rushed explanation of my knowledge on the subject, I'll just summarise the key points here: 1*The Quran implies that the Injil is a REVEALED scripture given to Isa (Jesus), 2*'The' Bible is NOT a set book, and it is NOT a revealed scripture. Christians regard it as an 'inspired' 'book', I would contest this. 3*Where is the Injil now? We have no idea. Anyone who labels it 'gospel' or 'gospel' is either ignorant of the facts, or is arrogant and assumes false knowledge... I have purposefully not written this as an actual answer, because I cannot..

Comment: ..directly answer your question. I hope this has helped you on your way, though.

Comment: Oh yeah just to add an aditional point, I believe the the 'Old Testament' (Jewish Bible) to be revealed scripture that has been corrupted, which is also the Islamic viewpoint. The 'New Testament' was written by various human authors. I am not sure if Allah inspired any of it, and personally do not regard it as holy scripture. Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Testament

Comment: Also, reading the introductory paragraph on this page will sum it up pretty nicely: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_in_Islam We believe that Jesus was given a holy scripture. We now have no idea where it is, and can only speculate that some fragments of it could be found in the older texts of the 'New Testament'. Muslims completely reject Pauline doctrine, though.

Comment: mashallah, this is a very nice answer i agree with your answer and Allah knows best, Arabic is a tough language and some words are just better not translated as they may mislead other that's why in my question i didn't say psalms and bible, all of this is hidden to hide the truth, to hide what is actually written in these holy books

Comment: By the time of our prophet PBUH Jews and Christians used to join Islam because of what is mentioned in their books about him, probably this is one of the reasons these books are hidden away

Answer (score 1):

Salams,

If you have referred the Bible, you will notice that it is written by various human authors. For eg:

- Gospel of Mark(Teachings of Jesus according to Mark)
- Gospel of Luke(Teachings of Jesus according to Luke)
- Gospel of Mathew(Teachings of Jesus according to Mathew)
- Gospel of John(Teachings of Jesus according to John)

Now these books are written by people after Isa(as) was raised up in heaven.
Injil is referred as the book which was reveled 'during the life of Isa(as)'s stay on earth'. It was reveled to him, and not the one which are written later on.

Hope it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complicated question. As Tehreem has mentioned in his [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/18568/11938), there are no perfect answers for this. But at the most what we can do is we can guess.

As clearly stated, Injeel was revealed onto Prophet Jesus(pbuh) during his lifetime on earth. So, now if we extract just the words of Jesus (pbuh) alone from the 4 canonical Gospels, what we are left with is this [Teachings of Jesus in his words](http://www.teachingsofjesus-inhiswords.com/) (Note: Consider his words [before his death](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23677/did-jesuspbuh-really-appear-to-the-disciples))

So, from this we can guess some of the words are his own, which he spoke out of the Hikmah(intellect) which was given to him, and it can be believed that at least a few of the words from [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23677/did-jesuspbuh-really-appear-to-the-disciples) are from God, i.e. that hey belong to Injil which was revealed onto him.

But although it is very difficult to make exact distinction between which words are of Jesus(pbuh) and which words are of God.

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score 0):

The Injil was the revelation sent down to prophet Isa (Jesus). The Injil is one of the four revelations recognised by Islam. The 4 revelations being:

Torah
Zabur
Injil
Qur'an
The word Injil is often used in the Qur'an, the hadith and early Muslim documents to refer to the revelations made by God to Jesus - it had never been compiled in the form of a literal book, revealed only as an oral book:

نَزَّلَ عَلَيْكَ الْكِتَابَ بِالْحَقِّ مُصَدِّقًا لِّمَا بَيْنَ يَدَيْهِ وَأَنزَلَ التَّوْرَاةَ وَالْإِنجِيلَ

He has sent down upon you, [O Muhammad], the Book in truth, confirming what was before it. And He revealed the Torah and the Gospel. (Qur'an 3:3)

From what the Qur'an tells us, this message was revealed to Isa (as) who went through great hardship to spread the message of Allah. Allah supported him with miracles to evidence his prophethood to his people:

Speaking from the cradle
Creating birds from clay
Healing the blind leaper
Power over death
Table of food from heaven
And so on.

Below is a verse from the Qur'an talking about the table of food from the heavens.

> قَالُوا نُرِيدُ أَن نَّأْكُلَ مِنْهَا وَتَطْمَئِنَّ قُلُوبُنَا
>   وَنَعْلَمَ أَن قَدْ صَدَقْتَنَا وَنَكُونَ عَلَيْهَا مِنَ الشَّاهِدِينَ
>
> They said, "We wish to eat from it and let our hearts be reassured and
>   know that you have been truthful to us and be among its witnesses."
>   (Qur'an 5:113)

As you can see, his followers asked him to do a miracle for them to believe the words he speaks.

The Injil was revealed to Isa (as) comparable to how the Qur'an was revealed to the Prophet Muhammad (saw):

> فَآتَيْنَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا مِنْهُمْ أَجْرَهُمْ ۖ وَكَثِيرٌ
>   مِّنْهُمْ فَاسِقُونَ
>
> Then We sent following their footsteps Our messengers and followed
>   [them] with Jesus, the son of Mary, and gave him the Gospel. And We
>   placed in the hearts of those who followed him compassion and mercy
>   and monasticism, which they innovated; We did not prescribe it for
>   them except [that they did so] seeking the approval of Allah . But
>   they did not observe it with due observance. So We gave the ones who
>   believed among them their reward, but many of them are defiantly
>   disobedient. (Qur'an 57:27)

Conclusion

The revelation to Isa (as) known as the Injil has not been transmitted faithfully to us - undergoing changes, necessitating yet another messenger, the Prophet Muhammad (saw), to convey the truth.