# Who are the people of zaboor?

Tags: quran, bible, torah

I was taught that there were 4 holy books revealed by the Almighty. The holy Quran, the Injeel, The Thaurath and the Zaboor. We know what happened to the people of Injeel and Taurath. What happened to the people of Zaboor? Do they still exist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What "book" is referred to in the phrase "People of the Book"?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1141/what-book-is-referred-to-in-the-phrase-people-of-the-book)

Comment: @azam well i can see the relation, but he's asking about a specific book and this doesn't seem to be answered in your linked Question. On the other hand i think the answers there still could be elaborated!

Comment: Also, Saboor of Dawood it is translated as Psalms of prophet David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same as people of the tawrath and Enjeel. As Zaboor was revealed to the Prophet David/Dawod (Peace be upon him) as we can read in different Verses of the Qur'an:

> - ...and to David We gave the book [of Psalms] ([4:163](http://legacy.quran.com/4/163))
> - ...and to Dawud (David) We gave the Zabur (Psalms). ([17:55](http://legacy.quran.com/17/55))
> - And We have already written in the book [of Psalms] after the [previous] mention that the land [of Paradise] is inherited by My righteous servants. ([21:105](http://legacy.quran.com/21/105))

I would recommend  you to read also for example the translation of Muhsin Khan for those Verses!

and Zabur is what Christians and Jews call [Psalms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zabur)!

---

Note that beside the Zabur the Qur'an also tell us about the scriptures of Ibrahim/Abraham (Peace be upon him):

Which are indicated in

> - Say, [O believers], "We have believed in Allah and what has been revealed to us and what has been revealed to Abraham ... ([2:138](http://legacy.quran.com/2/136))
> - Say, "We have believed in Allah and in what was revealed to us and what was revealed to Abraham, ... ([3:84](http://legacy.quran.com/3/84))

and clearly quoted:

> - (36) And [(referring to the scriptures) of] Abraham, who fulfilled [his obligations] - (37) ([53:36-37](http://legacy.quran.com/53/36-37))
> - (18) The scriptures of Abraham and Moses (19). ([87:18-19](http://legacy.quran.com/87/18-19))

Feel free to read more about it [here](https://islamqa.info/en/126004)

---

And Allah knows best!