# How many books / kitabs was sent down from Allah SWT

Tags: ahlul-kitab

I'm new in studying about islam, How many books / kitabs about religion (whether existing or non existing till today) has been sent down from Allah SWT to the earth according to the quran ? and which are the prophets that receives it?

Comment: It may seem like an obvious question, let's see what answer we will get, if any

Comment: I think your inquiry is covered in my answer https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29770/people-of-zaboor/29781#29781 see also https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1141/what-book-is-referred-to-in-the-phrase-people-of-the-book

Comment: I can see it's kind of related. Nevertheless, I'm pretty sure though, that those OP questions are definitely different than mine. But you are correct that the answer are somewhat covered there, as a side explanation to the answer of the original OP question. But still the OP was asking a different question than mine.

Answer (score -1):

1) Tawrat – This is the revelation that Allah sent to Musa (Moses), peace be upon him.
2) Zabur – This is the revelation that Allah sent to Daud (David), peace be upon him.
3) Injeel(Gospel)  – This is the revelation that Allah sent to Eesa (Jesus), peace be upon him.
4) Quran – This is the revelation that Allah sent to Muhammad, peace be upon him.

1) Torah for Jews 
2)Gospel for Christians
3) Zabur for Sabians I suppose
4) Quran(the last book)  for muslims

Comment: I think there maybe one more, according to the quran

Comment: I think It's mention in two different surah, CMIIW

Comment: @Rextia Nope, Those 4 books were revealed by God

Comment: @Rextia Yes, It is mentioned those books in surah.

Comment: Heh pretty sure, what about the Scripture of Abraham then?

Comment: "I suppose" is not a sign of a good and well elaborated answer.

Comment: @Medi1Saif What answer?

Comment: @Medi1Saif Aaaa, because I was not sure if Zabur was for Sabians and that’s why